# Grails 2.4.4, Multiple DataSources, Using GORM finder on Domain class results in: Method on class [User] was used outside of a Grails application

Tags: grails

I'm trying to put in a default user in the BootStrap.groovy init closure. It's resulting in this error:
Method on class [com.exmaple.AdminUser] was used outside of a Grails application.

My BootStrap.groovy file:

```
class BootStrap {
   def init = { servletContext ->
      if (!AdminUser.findByEmail("eric@example.com")) {
         AdminUser eric = new AdminUser(
               email: "eric@exmaple.com",
               firstname: "Eric",
               lastname: "Berry",
               password: "password"
         ).save()
         if (eric.hasErrors()) {
            log.error("Error creating admin user: ${eric.errors}")
         }
      }
   }
   def destroy = {
   }
}
```

My DataSource.groovy file (Relevant Bits):

```
dataSources {
   dataSource {
      ...
   }
   adminDataSource {
      pooled = true
      jmxExport = true
      driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
      username = "sa"
      password = ""
   }
}
hibernate {
   cache.use_second_level_cache = false
   cache.use_query_cache = false
   cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
   singleSession = true // configure OSIV singleSession mode
}

// environment specific settings
environments {
   development {
      dataSources {
         dataSource {
            ...
         }
         adminDataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:admin_user_db;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And my AdminUser object:

```
class AdminUser {
   String id
   Date dateCreated
   Date lastUpdated

   String email
   String firstname
   String lastname
   String password

   static constraints = {
      id(maxSize: 36)
      email(nullable: false, blank: false, email: true, unique: true)
      firstname(nullable: false, blank: false)
      lastname(nullable: false, blank: false)
      password(nullable: false, blank: false)
   }

   static mapping = {
      datasource('adminDataSource')
      id(generator: 'uuid2')
   }

   def beforeInsert() {
      encodePassword()
   }

   def beforeUpdate() {
      if (isDirty('password')) {
         encodePassword()
      }
   }

   private void encodePassword() {
      password = BCrypt.hashpw(password, BCrypt.gensalt(12))
   }
}
```

Lastly, my hibernate version is (from BuildConfig.groovy):

```
runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1"
```

I'm doing something similarly in another Grails app, using same version of Grails and Hibernate, and that one is working fine. Two differences I can see is that:

1. I'm not using multiple datasources
2. The app that is working uses a Service to create the default user, which is injected into the BootStrap.groovy file.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, or how to fix it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using wrong datasource name (`adminDataSource`) in the `DataSource.groovy` file.

In multiple datasource, all the datasoure name must have the prefix `dataSource_`, except the default datasource.

So just change your datasource name from `adminDataSource` to `dataSource_adminDataSource`.

Comment: The error is still happening. The documentation doesn't mention anything like this. http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/conf.html#multipleDatasources
In the example, the second datasource is named 'lookup', not 'dataSource_lookup'.

Comment: Correction! This did solve it, thanks very much! I was looking at the documentation for the latest version of Grails, which turns out to be 3.0.0RC2. Looks like they're changing the way multiple datasources are done. The documentation for Grails 2.4.4 shows the example as you describe.
http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/guide/conf.html#multipleDatasources